# Convert an email into its raw format using java

Tags: java, email

I tried until now to create an object of type `MimeMessage` using JavaMail api, and after that to obtain its raw representation, but with no success. The only thing that I could obtain is a raw representation of the **content** of the email, but the header, subject, or recipients were not included. I am interested in any suggestions, any java libraries, that could help me in creating an email object, and after that obtain its raw representation. The raw representation should look something like this:

```
received: from imta14.emeryville.ca.mail.myisp.net ([nn.nn.30.46])
by alnrmxc19.isp.net (alnrmxc19) with ESMTP
id <20080930215116a19007q9u6e>; Tue, 30 Sep 2008 21:51:16 +0000
X-Originating-IP: [nn.nn.30.46]
Received: from libertatea.go ([nn.nn.161.160])
by IMTA14.mail.isp.net with isp
id M9qy1a00V3TwUto0E9rELB; Tue, 30 Sep 2008 21:51:15 +0000
X-Authority-Analysis: v=1.0 c=1 a=DZlucjOqAY8A:10 a=mnGO974OAAAA:8
a=9MJFf195B83LjESASTQA:9 a=Lm7NQ261g8eJHgoaELoA:7
a=7Narey355jFQWZRww2lj1r9-lCkA:4 a=8COHQAuY8ZYA:10 a=zEVpGHA-kecA:10
a=37WNUvjkh6kA:10
Received: by libertatea.go id hm1nfa0di0sn for <xxx@myisp.net>; Sun,30 Sep 2018 09:36:35
+0300 (envelope-from <Hometown.Quotes_ary@mousemegadot.com>)
Message-ID: <79864795@mousemegadot.com>
Date: Sun, 30 Sep 2018 09:36:35 +0300
From: "Hometown Quotes" <Hometown.Quotes_ary@mousemegadot.com>
To: dummy@myisp.net
Subject: Find Affordable Auto Insurance Today
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-UID: 79864795.modhnrfo.jhhnk.1
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="0-1411506895-1200484069=:66653"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-PMFLAGS: 570966272 9 1 PE71PYHD.CNM 
X-UC-Weight: [# ] 51
X-CC-Diagnostic: Test 'LazyHTML Tolerant' (51)

--0-1411506895-1200484069=:66653
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

--0-1411506895-1200484069=:66653
Content-transfer-encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1; DelSp="Yes"; format="flowed"
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code and ask the question around what specific issues you have encountered. If you need it written for you Rent a Coder will do it at a price.

Comment: Ok, so I've tried the method Message.getInputStream() which is the only method from JavaMail api that returns raw content, but it returns only the **content** of the message, without the header, subject, etc.  I need all the content of the object of type Message to be obtained in the raw format.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you are looking for is [MimeMessag#writeTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#writeTo%28java.io.OutputStream%29/MimeMessage.html#writeTo%28java.io.OutputStream%29) which outputs the message as an RFC 822 format stream.

An example of using `writeTo` to convert a `MimeMessage` to a String.

```
MimeMessage mimeMessage;

// mimeMessage get assigned

ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
mimeMessage.writeTo(output);
String rawEmail = output.toString();
```

Comment: You, sir, just made my day. Thank you very much for your effort. This was the correct solution. Thank you again.

Comment: Just a typo: "ouput" change to "output" (ouput - no such property)